# Script to check if all files are under the same root SVN

Tags: svn

HI guys,

i have this method of working with branches and some times what happens is that some of the files under my checked out directory point to the wrong root i.e they will be pointing to a file in one of the branch instead of the actual branch.

I was wondering if there is a script that can verify if all the files in my checked out folder are under the same root..

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: A script for which environment? Windows cmd? Bash shell?

Comment: windows. and also my assumption is the root node is pointing to the right repo thus i dont want to give the input string for the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick: Suppose the expected root is something like `https://svn.server.local/trunk/`, execute the following in the local copy's root folder:

```
svn info -R | grep "URL:" | grep -v "URL: https://svn.server.local/trunk/"
```

Or, on Windows:

```
svn info -R | FIND "URL:" | FIND /V "URL: https://svn.server.local/trunk/"
```

The output will be the URL list of files *not* under the root repository.

Comment: awesome thanks. that worked.. i modifed it a little to suit my needs.